# Termius Application Not Show

Tags: ssh, 18.10

i just install Termius Version 3.2.6 - Released 15 October, 2018 on My Ubuntu 18.10.
all already done. but i cant open this app if i click termius on my Ubuntu. please help. Thanks

Comment: What is this application about? Is it in Ubuntu software center? If not, how did you install it?

Comment: Hey @vanadium thanks for your reply. This application for remote ssh. this app available at software center, but i cannt open. Putty also cannt open in my Ubuntu.

Comment: You may want to add that bit of detail to the body of your question. You may want to open the application from the terminal instead of from your application menu: this way, error messages may be visible that can help identify the origin of the problem.